# Is there a general way to get difficulty from any cryptocurrency coin?

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

Is there a way to get the difficulty from any coin even if there isn't a blockchain site like http://blockchain.info/ (they have an API)? I need to access it programmatically and i want to have it from the source so ripping it from a site that already lists them all isn't an option. Im using a vps Ubuntu server so the ram and mainly the diskspace is limited hence, i cant have alot of blockchains installed on it.

Answer (score 0):

Most if not all have daemons you can use. You can run the daemon on the server and make a request for it. They should all be similar to the php one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It would be great if i could have them all installed on the server but im on a vps server so the diskspace is limited and as far as i understand it, the daemon has to download and maintain the blockchain?

Comment: @Sultanen Yep. For each daemon you have to download the entire blockchain. There is actually no other way to do this. The one thing you can do is not download the blockchain for bitcoin but use this instead. https://blockchain.info/api/json_rpc_api That will save you around 13 gigs. For other altcoins you have to use the daemon.